# override billing and shipping address in admin

Tags: php, magento

using Magento for sales reps and they can create order in Magento admin. I need to change in "Create New order" the Billing and Shipping address fields. I need to change the sequence and change "Zip/Postal Code" to "County".  Is there a way to change Customer Address fields in admin ?

Answer (score 0):

try this, to add a new custom field to customer address:

```
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/
```

Comment: actually i dont need to create a new field. i need to override ZIP/Postal Code and rename it to County. Where is this file located?

Comment: also i need to swap country with ZIP/Postal code in admin shipping and billing address. does somebody know where is this file located ?